# Meaning of Zero Before Number in Java

Tags: java

I have a code like this, but I don't know why result variable have false value after execution the code

```
int x = 234;
boolean result = (x<0250);
```

and also why the following code doesn't work properly?

```
System.out.println(0250);
```

it prints 168 !! why?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer literals starting with `0` are *octal* (base 8) not decimal (base 10).

Your options are

```
hexadecimal = 0x0C;
decimal = 12; 
octal = 014;
binary = 0b1100;
```

Answer (score 0):

A number that looks like `0x` followed by an integer (using the digits 0-9 and A-F) is a hexadecimal (base 16) number.

A number that looks like `0` followed by an integer (using the digits 0-7) is an octal (base 8) number.